# Problem with Newton--Raphson Implementation of Inverse-Linked Gamma GLM in R

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution

Recently, I've been trying to implement functions in R that use Newton--Raphson to find the MLE of parameters for various GLMs. My focus has (thus far) been on data with responses $y$ that are distributed along members of the exponential family with sufficient statistic $T(y) = y$.

For clarity, I've been following the notation where the probability density function of $y$ parameterized by $\eta$ follows:
$$f(y; \eta) = b(y) \: \exp \left\{ \eta y - a(\eta) \right\}$$

Glossing over the math, I've come to understand that the gradient and Hessian of the log-likelihood $\ell$ can be expressed as follows:
$$\nabla_\theta \ell(\theta) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m} \left[ y^{(i)} - a^\prime(\theta^Tx^{(i)}) \right] x^{(i)} $$
$$H_\theta(\ell) = - \sum_{i=1}^{m} x^{(i)}x^{(i)T} a^{\prime\prime}(\theta^Tx^{(i)})$$
for some vector of parameters $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ over a training set $\left\{\left(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)}\right)\right\}_{i=1}^{m}$.

For exponentially distributed responses, I found that:
$$a^\prime(\theta^T x) = -(\theta^Tx)^{-1} \quad \text{and} \quad a^{\prime\prime}(\theta^T x) = (\theta^T x)^{-2}$$

The output of my function, however, does not agree with the estimates from the built-in `glm` function in `R`. I've been calling the function as follows:

`glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))`

The data was generated with:

`x1 = runif(100)
x2 = runif(100)
y = rexp(100, -(x1 + x2))`

And finally, my function is:

`my.glm = function(x.mat, y.mat, first.func, second.func, iters)
{
  nobs = nrow(x.mat)
  x.mat = cbind(rep(1.0, nobs), x.mat)
  theta.mat = matrix(rep(0.5, ncol(x.mat)), nrow = ncol(x.mat))
  x.dat.list = vector("list", length = nobs)
  for(ob in 1:nobs)
  {
    x.dat = matrix(as.numeric(x.mat[ob, ]), ncol = 1)
    x.dat.list[[ob]] = x.dat %*% t(x.dat)
  }
  for(k in 1:iters)
  {
    hess.sum = 0
    grad.sum = 0
    for(ob in 1:nobs)
    {
      x.dat = matrix(as.numeric(x.mat[ob, ]), ncol = 1)
      eta.val = (t(x.dat) %*% theta.mat)[1,1]
      hess.sum = hess.sum - second.func(eta.val) * x.dat.list[[ob]]
      grad.sum = grad.sum + (y.mat[ob, 1] - first.func(eta.val)) * x.dat
    }
    theta.mat = theta.mat - ginv(hess.sum) %*% grad.sum
  }
  return(theta.mat)
}`

And I've set:

`first.func = function(x){-1/x}
second.func = function(x){1/x^2}`

I tried it with linear regression, logistic regression, and poisson regression using the appropriate functions, and the outputs seem to agree with those of `glm`. At this point, I have no idea how to go about diagnosing the problem. Does anyone have any insights on this? It would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you looked at the [glm source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/glm.R)?

Comment: 1. Do you get the same MLE with your function as would get with the parameters returned by `R`'s implementation? 2. Is your MLE *better* than the one returned by `R`? 3. How different are your estimates? eg. Are we talking `abs(max(x-y)) ~ 1e-3` or `1e-13`? 4. Avoid using the `ginv`; just using `solve` is adequate (so QR-decomp.).